# Path Error, YUI compressor .NET

Tags: .net, msbuild, yui-compressor

I'm trying to use [YUI compressor for .NET](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) as an MSBUILD event

```
$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe "$(ProjectDir)MSBuild\MSBuildSettings.xml"
\p:CssOutputFile="$(ProjectDir)styles.css"
\p:JavaScriptOutputFile="$(ProjectDir)scripts.js"
```

This is my Pre-Build event command line...
In the output it seems like the task succeeds because it says "Finished Css/Javascript compression" but it later crashes with an error **The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

My path contains whitespaces could that be the problem? If so, is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of providing the output paths in the command, I placed them in the Settings xml for YUI. That way the files generated as they should